# Wmi ManagedComputer SetServiceAccount gives "Set service account failed"

Tags: sql-server, powershell, configuration, automation

I'm trying to automate the post-install configuration of an SQL+SSRS server installation (MS SQL 2012 Express) -- I think it's more or less [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh389764.aspx). However, this is my first foray into Powershell, and I have never before configured or even used MS SQL. My server is a Windows 2008 R2 virtual machine, where I'm an admin, and the SQL server is installed locally (not clustered). I'm using Powershell v2.0 to run the following snippet (as an admin):

```
Write-Output("- Setting service account ...")
Write-Output("  - Loading assembly ...")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement") | out-null
Write-Output("  - Loading server ...")
$mc = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer "$hostname"
Write-Output("  - Loading service ...")
#$service = $mc.Services | Where {$_.Name -eq "MSSQL`$$sqlInstanceName"}
$service = $mc.Services | Where {$_.Name -eq "ReportServer`$$sqlInstanceName"}
Write-Output("  - Changing service account credentials ...")
$service.SetServiceAccount("$hostname\sa", "$sapwd")
Write-Output("  - Commit ...")
$service.Alter()
Write-Output("- OK.")
```

Between "Changing service account credentials" and "Commit", my code fails with this message:

```
Exception calling "SetServiceAccount" with "2" argument(s):
"Set service account failed."
```

The `$sapwd` is the password given during the SQL server installation. I'm never asked for a corresponding user name, but am told that there is an "SA" user is implied. I don't have a Windows user by that name on the local machine; I'm unsure of what users are defined in a (newly-installed) SQL server.

My goal here is the equivalent of using the GUI to set the "Service Account" to "Use built-in account: Network Service",  The code snippet is based on [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/11/03/use-powershell-to-change-sql-server-s-service-accounts.aspx) code. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739096/sql-server-failover-cluster-service-account-change-through-powershell) is not totally unrelated, but (a) it's not answered, and (b) I don't use clustering.

Many others have had this problem, but there don't seem to be any solid answers that work for me. How can I even *find information about* what this error means, and how to work around it?

*Bonus*

I'll also need to change the "Web Service URL" and the "Report Manager URL"; if you've any tips on how to do that you'll save me a bunch of hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sa` is a *database* user (the builtin database administrator account), not a *Windows* user. For running a service you need a Windows user account. Usually either a dedicated account you created for running the service (with the required permissions/privileges) or one of the builtin default accounts like `NT AUTHORITY\Network Service` or `NT AUTHORITY\Local Service`.

Pass an empty string as the second parameter when using one of the builtin accounts, since they don't have a password:

```
$service.SetServiceAccount('NT AUTHORITY\Network Service', '')
```

With that said, normally you should have specified the runas account for the database service during the installation, so there shouldn't be a need for changing it afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy reply. I tried supplying `NT AUTHORITY\Network Service` (along with the `$sapwd`) but got the same error. I then tried the credentials for the currently-logged-in user, and that seemed(!) to work. This is probably not the best user for the task, though, and I shall ask the client about user configuration.

Comment: Uhh, thanks Microsoft, for making the account `NT AUTHORITY\Network Service` _localisation-dependent_. >_< I'm trying to understand "virtual accounts" and whether they have a role here, and if not -- how to find out the local naming of the "network service" account.

Comment: _Update:_ The localisation challenge is now [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34767058/get-localised-account-name-for-the-nt-authority-network-service-account-or-h).

Comment: The builtin accounts don't have a password, so don't use `$sapwd` for them (unless the variable is empty). See updated answer.

Comment: Well, (a) if I supply a blank string for password, then I get the error message again; and (b) I don't know "normally", I just know how a (this) clean install works. I wonder if this will break horribly once it hits the Real World. :(

Comment: Hmm... weird. But like I said before, you shouldn't need to change the runas account in the first place, as it should have already been set during setup.

Comment: Hmm, well then maybe I'm doing the wrong thing, and asking the wrong question. I've asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34769856/change-service-account-to-built-in-network-service).